# Default Argument in Virtual Function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, default-arguments

Please help me find the reasons behind it:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class A {
  public:
     virtual void fun(int a = 5) { cout<<a; }
};
class B::public A {
  public:
     void fun(int a = 10) {
        cout<<"Inside A::B::fun().\n";
        cout<<"\n"<<a;
     }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  A *obj = new B();
  obj->fun();
  reutrn 0;
}
```

Althought it is calling B::fun(), still printing 5, why and how that work.?

Comment: yes @Mark, i'm using MS VC++ 2010 Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A *obj = new B();
obj->fun();
```

In this code, `fun()` is invoked polymorphically - the caller uses (only) knowledge of `A::fun()`, but the call is dispatched to a pointer that redirects to the implementation for `B::fun()`.  That function argument - `a` / `5` - is provided by the caller before the redirected call though (way before - during compilation) - `A`'s default is seen, not `B`'s.

If you want something like you seem to expect, you might find it works to have `A::fun(int a = -1)` or some other sentinel value, with the implementations of `fun` checking for the sentinel value then replacing it with 5 or 10 as desired.  That way, the implementation-specific values are incorporated during the call, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are not characterized by dynamic dispatch behaviour. They are static.
Scott Meyers discusses this in detail in "Effective C++"